# Google Maps embed disable user controls

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-embed

I am trying to add a simple google map to my site using the embed feature on maps.google.com.

Here is the code that has been generated for me:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m12!1m8!1m3!1d2391.716465442018!2d-0.6309220000000001!3d53.169126500000004!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!2m1!1sAqua+House%2C+Lincoln+Enterprise+Park%2C+Newark+Road%2C+Lincoln%2C+LN5+9FP!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1418907912180" width="100%" height="410" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

What I can't find out is how to disable users controls, so that if they accidentally scrolled down over the map, it doesn't zoom in loads.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have much control with iframe. The best choice would be to use  Google Maps JavaScript API v3 and set `disableDefaultUI: true`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm horrible for doing this, but I wanted the simplicity of the embed, but without the controls as well:

Just made the iframe twice as big and hid the overflow, problem solved.

If anyone can see an issue with this, I'm curious...

```css
div.map-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
iframe.map {
  width: 200%;
  height: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25%;
  left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-container">
  <iframe class="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2689.289359274373!2d-122.35146608361184!3d47.62050627918564!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x5490151f4ed5b7f9%3A0xdb2ba8689ed0920d!2sSpace+Needle!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1478295713465" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

EDIT:  Misread the OP slightly.  You could overlay a div over the top of the map, and any interaction in that place would interact with the div and not the map itself.

Haven't played around with it, but you could also give the iframe a:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

May not work in every browser; but it's a path you could explore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in get-parameters the option `signed_in=false`
It work if use the js-api:

```
<script>
    // Google map
    function initMap() {

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
        zoom: 17,
        center: {lat: <lat>, lng: <lng>},
        scrollwheel: false,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
      });
      var image = 'images/map-icon.png';
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: <lat>, lng: <lng>},
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    }
</script>
<script async defer
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=false&callback=initMap">
</script>
```